# More than one mule-deploy descriptions found in application

Tags: java, mule-studio

I have 5 muleflows. It gives error while running --

The error is --

```
 Reading plugins from C:/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201307221331/mule/plugins
 Exception in thread "main" org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: More than one mule-  deploy descriptors found in application 'Project'
at   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultAppBloodhound.fetch(DefaultAppBloodhound.java:84)
    at   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultApplicationFactory.createApp(DefaultApplication Factory.java:42)
    at   org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.createApplication(ApplicationDeployer.java:93)
at   org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:116)
```

How to resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple mule-deploy files. Editing in emacs can cause this. Delete the duplicates.